# get records in many to many relation in node js depend on sequelize

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

Hello I have product and city with relation many to many between this two models my question is how i can get all product that not belongs to some cities

let products=product.findAll()

so can any one help me about this problem and resolve it and thanks for every one